# NativeScript: How do i persist custom gradle.properties outside the platform-folder?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-cli

Is there any way to store a custom "gradle.properties" outside the folder "platforms/". I want to store this file outside the platforms-folder because the content in there can be overridden if i do an update of the platform.

## I've tried following

- Put the gradle.properties inside App_Resources/Android -> didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [@nativescript/android **v6.1.0**](https://github.com/NativeScript/android/releases/tag/v6.1.0) user defined gradle properties are supported.

Create a new file `<App_Resources>/Android/gradle.properties`

This file will be picked up by NativeScript and override any existing properties.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I haven't had the chance to test this, but I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with app.gradle or build or settings.gradle as per these [guidelines](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html).
You can update these files  App_Resources/Android and whenever you build your project, it will override gradle.properties file in platform folder.

Comment: The "gradle.properties" inside App_Resources/Android doesn't have any use. Is there any other way apart from changing auto generated "gradle.properties" under platforms folder?